# Trouble in traversal of list of url

Tags: python

I want to fetch data from about 900 urls. But program stop after 30 - 40 urls.

```
opener = urllib2.build_opener()
    opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]

    with open('Labgodata.csv') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
        for line in reader:
            sleep(0.2)
            getdata(line['URL'])
```

Here 'Labgodata.csv' is file containing urls.

Comment: What exception (if any)? Where? What have you tried?

Comment: probably `line` is a `string` not `dict`.

Comment: please provide the list of links (first ~50) and point on those which fail to get processed. Is it one certain link or random ones?